# How can I remove a last pipe delimiter from a pipe-delimited file in Unix?

Tags: text-processing

How can I remove a last pipe delimiter from a pipe delimited file in Unix?

My input lines look like:

```
1|GAbriel|10 ground floor|naik Badi|trend|account|detail|hints||||||
```

Expected output is:

```
1|GAbriel|10 ground floor|naik Badi|trend|account|detail|hints|||||
```

I just need to eliminate the last pipe out of continuous pipe at the end of each record.

Comment: Is the `|` you want to remove always at the end of a line, or might there be other characters after it?

Comment: its the '|' always

Answer (score 3):

Try `sed 's/|$//' filename`. And be sure to read the man page of `sed`.

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/|$//' file
```

With `awk`:

```
awk -F '|' 'NF--' OFS='|' file
```